# Why is CDROM_TOC.Length an UCHAR[2] instead of WORD?

Tags: c, winapi, ioctl, uint16

In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddcdrm/ns-ntddcdrm-_cdrom_toc) the length is made of two unsigned bytes:

*Length*

*Indicates the length, in bytes, of the table of contents data. This length value does not include the length of the Length member itself.*

When you form a `WORD` in Little Endian, indeed it is the correct value, but why did they choose to not use a `WORD` directly ?

Comment: How weird -- either it should be a proper `WORD` (indicating, uh, Microsoft's native endianness?) or it should *at least* mention which of the two bytes are the low and high end. (Which would be to indicate this structure does not care about native endianness.)

Comment: It seems like all the related structures use `UCHAR` arrays rather than larger datatypes. No doubt somewhere the endianness is documented (maybe it's set by the ISO standard or something).

Comment: I think I've found the answer and posted one, just a guess but actually the notion of endianness might be a little too high-level at this level...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging deep through [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddcdrm/ns-ntddcdrm-_cdrom_toc):

*For information about the permissible values for this member, see specification T10/1363-D, by National Committee for Information Technology Standards (NCITS).*

This leads us to here:

https://ia802909.us.archive.org/35/items/mmc3r10g/mmc3r10g.pdf

When you look through these 471 pages for the word *endian*, there are zero results, for the word *integer* there are only five results.

But in 5.23.2 TOC/PMA/ATIP Response Data Format 0000b, we can infer that since in that table next to *Bit 0* there is *(LSB)*, it is indeed a 16-bit integer in <s>Little Endian</s> Big Endian (thanks Hans).

In conclusion, they just made the struct look as it's laid out in these specs.

Comment: Table 232 in the spec, the MSB (most significant byte) is byte 0, LSB is byte 1.  That's big-endian.  And a good reason to use UCHAR[2] instead of WORD.

Comment: Thank you Hans :)